# Selenium will not scroll to the end on a infinite scroll webpage

Tags: selenium

I am trying to scrape all the men's shoes on Nike website using selenium and beautifulsoup.

Because the webpage is an infinite scroll, I am using selenium to scroll to the end.
However, it won't scroll beyond the first page with Selenium.
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'https://www.nike.com/kr/ko_kr/w/men/fw'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 10


try: 
    driver.get(url)
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height

    content = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("ncss-col-sm-6 ncss-col-md-6 ncss-col-lg-4 grid-wall-list-item")
    print("selenium says " + str(len(content)))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

    shoes = soup.find_all("li",{"class":"ncss-col-sm-6 ncss-col-md-6 ncss-col-lg-4 grid-wall-list-item"})


finally:
    driver.quit()


print(len(shoes))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to scroll on the container's height:

> div.ncss-container

So try this:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);", driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.ncss-container"))
```

Comment: It still didn't work....For clarification, do I need to get container's scroll height as well? (ie. get container's height on the codes with return statement)

Comment: Oops. I see an error in what I was trying to do. Will edit

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you also explain how you were able to tell the container had to be scrolled not window?